# Opening the save all attachments dialog

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to open the save all attachments dialog so I can choose what to save and where and not save all the attachments together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click buttons as described here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/commandbars-executemso-method-office

```
Private Sub SaveAllAttachments_ExecuteMso()

Dim objItem As Object
Dim objInsp As Inspector

Set objItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

Set objInsp = objItem.GetInspector
' Hover over the "SAveAllAttachments..." button in the dialog for adding buttons.
' You will see SaveAttachments, in brackets, at the end of the text.
objInsp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("SaveAttachments")

ExitRoutine:
    Set objItem = Nothing
    Set objInsp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I just need to add a command to open the message first and I'm good :D