# How to Open Insert Item Dialog From Outlook Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My project requires user to select and attach a existing mail from Outlook to new mail. I am trying to find how to get the below dialog to show in outlook using VBA to allow user to select the mail to attach. Could anyone guide me.

[image]

I tried to look at outlook object if it supports showing any such dialog through VBA but could not find any way to display it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening the save all attachments dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278498/opening-the-save-all-attachments-dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself after a lot of trial and error. Here is my solution.

It demonstrates how to attach an email to a new email as well as how to get email item selection from user input and then save all the attachments from that email. Hope it is helpful.

```
Dim FilePath As String
    
Function getUserEmailSelection() As Object
    Dim o As Object, mailWindow As Object
    Dim myItem As Object, objMsg As Object, oA As Object
    Set o = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    FilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd H-mm") & " "
    
    Set objMsg = o.CreateItem(0)
    Set mailWindow = objMsg.GetInspector
    mailWindow.Display
    mailWindow.WindowState = 1
    mailWindow.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "AttachItem"
    
    On Error GoTo DialogCancelled
    Set oA = objMsg.Attachments(1)
    objMsg.Close 1
    Set mailWindow = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    FilePath = FilePath & oA.Filename
    oA.SaveAsFile FilePath
    Set myItem = o.CreateItemFromTemplate(FilePath)
    Set getUserEmailSelection = myItem
    
    Exit Function
    
    DialogCancelled:
    Err.Clear
    objMsg.Close 1
    Set getUserEmailSelection = Nothing
End Function
```

For Testing, here is the code:

```
Sub SaveAllAttachments()
    Dim olMail As Object, objAttachments As Object, lngCount As Long
    Dim strFolderpath As String, strFile As String, i As Long
    strFolderpath = "C:\Users\BD\Local\New folder\"
    Set olMail = getUserEmailSelection()
    If Not olMail Is Nothing Then
    Set objAttachments = olMail.Attachments
        lngCount = objAttachments.Count
        If lngCount > 0 Then
            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
                strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).Filename
                strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
                objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
            Next
        End If
    Kill FilePath
    End If
End Sub
```